# What is the purpose of the jenkins User folder and what are these config files?

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In my Jenkins home dir I see these configs for all my users:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\users\someuser\config.xml"
```

What is this config? Looks like its caching their sessions or something? Do I need to backup these files? What woudl the impact be if the `users` folder got deleted?

I should add that Im using active directory for auth so these aren't internal jenkins users they are AD users. Which is why Im wondering what config jenkins is keeping for them

Comment: I reviewed my jenkins installation on Linux, and I don't see a jenkins  folder. I think this behavior is related to your jenkins installation on windows. No body uses jenkins on windows for real enviroments. For proof of concept is acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should backup those indeed. These folders contain user-specific configuration data, like public keys or api access tokens (see user's "configure" menu in the Web interface).

Comment: "public keys or api access tokens"- what keys and tokens? its using active directory for auth. Looks like it dynamically provisions a jenkins user from the active directory user when they login. If thats the case i should need to back them up right? what static info could there be here?

Comment: Keys are for using the CLI and REST APIs. Yes you should backup those.

Comment: ah so then if none of my users are using the REST API I shouldnt have to back this up right?

Comment: It depends. Some plugins allow for user-specific configuration data also. You're on safe side if you do backup; the amount of data is small, so the cost is low.

Comment: I thought UserContent folder was for user specific config data?

Comment: No. "userContent" allows to add custom content to the Jenkins' "web server". It is unrelated to configuration data.